# Communications Exception in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

i am searching the solution for the below problem , if you have any idea please share 
when I try to run a single query from java (jboss server), am getting the below exception (not frequently .)

```
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
The last packet successfully received from the server was43200 seconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 43200 seconds ago,
which is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'.
You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application,
increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' 
to avoid this problem.*
```

if connection is idle, it is closed by MySQL. in this case Java will give Can not write: broken pipe" or alike exception
but in this case, connection is not idle. it is working. so MySQL won’t close it. but Java is waiting for query result and cannot get it for 12 hours so it shows "Read Timeout" exception

Answer (score 2):

You need to use connection pool that manages these things for you, refer c3po, basic idea is you make a dummy query to keep connection alive periodically

Comment: actually am using NanoPoolDataSource already... if i go with dummy query . is that wont cause any other issue like traffic

Comment: no it is single query that doesn't return any data and you fire it like hourly

Comment: I dont get you. what is dummy query here. should i create empty table and started fetching the table data in loop.  can you please give some example .

Comment: validation query would be something like `select 1` and you test the connection during idle time

Comment: This error was happened , when ever the Big table(it has more than 20million records) get used in a query. so currently we optimized the query, in such a way that to process the record little faster, by introducing the temp tables intermediately. now a days we are not getting this error